# Any difference between const Class& and Class const&?

Tags: reference, const-correctness

Is there any difference between that expressions :

```
const Class&
Class const&
```

for example, when those are parameters of function ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference between `const Class&` and `Class const&`; similarly here is no difference between `const Class*` and `Class const*`.

And so,

```
void f1 (const Class& c)
```

and

```
void f1 (Class const& c)
```

are interchangeable with no difference.

Both versions denote a reference to a constant Class instance and can be used interchangeably.